# How to fix 'Native host has exited'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, electron, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to enable Google Chrome Native messaging between an extension and an Electron app on MacOS.

After having setup all mentioned in the doc (manifest and permission for enabling native messaging within an extension), when i try to open a connection between the app and extension i receive "Native host has exited".

This is the code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('org.alessandro.app',
    { text: "Hello" },
    function(response) {
      console.log("Received " + response);
  });
```

I'm not sure, but also disabling everything host side, i receive the same error. Maybe it happens before reaching the host but i'm not able to figure it out!

Comment: Most likely your host app is reading/writing stdio incorrectly.

Comment: I'm using this lib: https://github.com/jdiamond/chrome-native-messaging. Do you have any suggestion about what i lib i could use?

Comment: I would write the code myself. As for that library, assuming it's not buggy, try to [enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and see if there's a problem launching the host.

Comment: i receive only this error but i don't think it is related to my problem "ERROR:paint_controller.cc(548)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed"

Comment: Find any mentions of native host in the log, maybe it's not even registered properly.

Comment: there is nothing about "native host". The only one is "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Native host has exited.", source: chrome-extension://amfdmpdebgkhhgfmlhmbmlfjaneeedia/_generated_background_page.html (0)"

Comment: [How to fix Native Host Has Exited error in Chrome browser extension -- Native Messaging](//stackoverflow.com/q/27785153)

Comment: thank you!! i already saw this post and i tried to follow it but the error persist!